Contour integration of an integral
I am trying to determine the following integral by using the residue theorem
$$\int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\frac{{\gamma \left( {1/2,{\rm{i}}z} \right)\gamma \left( {1/2, - {\rm{i}}z} \right)}}{{{z^2} + 1}}{\rm{d}}z}$$
where $\gamma$ is the incomplete gamma function.
but it seems general methods fail to capture the solution in this case because there is a minus sign in the second incomplete Gamma function but a plus sign in the first incomplete Gamma function. There are two simple poles $\pm {\rm{i}}$ and the semi-circle on the upper plane is chosen as the contour

The result is
$$
\int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\frac{{\gamma \left( {1/2,{\rm{i}}x} \right)\gamma \left( {1/2, - {\rm{i}}x} \right)}}{{{x^2} + 1}}{\rm{d}}x} 
 = 2\pi {\rm{iRes}}\left( {f,{\rm{i}}} \right)
 = 1.55248 - 2.56225{\rm{i}}
$$
It is possible to obtain the numerical result in Mathematica by using NIntegrate, and the result is $2.59899$ which is different from the $1.55248 - 2.56225{\rm{i}}$. Hence, I wonder if I had made a mistake and whether an analytical solution exists for this integral. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Mathematica has a branch cut along the entire imaginary axis for the given integrand (depicted by the black vertical line here). The residue theorem won't work with your contour.

Partial answer By exploiting the symmetry of the integrand and rewriting it using $(8.4.6)$ (the same is obtained by Mathematica's FunctionExpand), we have
$$\newcommand{\erf}[1]{\operatorname{erf}\left(#1\right)}
\begin{align*}
I &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac12, ix\right) \Gamma\left(\frac12, -ix\right)}{x^2+1} \, dx \\
&= 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac12, ix\right) \Gamma\left(\frac12, -ix\right)}{x^2+1} \, dx \\
&= 2\pi \int_0^\infty \frac{\left(1 - \erf{\sqrt{ix}}\right) \left(1+\erf{-\sqrt{-ix}}\right)}{x^2+1} \, dx \\
&= \pi^2-2\pi\int_0^\infty\frac{\erf{\sqrt{ix}} - \erf{-\sqrt{-ix}} + \erf{\sqrt{ix}} \erf{-\sqrt{-ix}}}{x^2+1}\,dx \\
&= \pi^2 - 2\pi \left(I_1 - I_2 + I_3\right)
\end{align*}$$
using the principal branch of $\sqrt z$, $\arg z\in(-\pi,\pi)$. I'm not yet sure how to handle $I_3$, but we can proceed with the former two integrals by parts:
$$\begin{align*}
I_{1,2} &= \int_0^\infty \frac{\erf{\pm \sqrt{\pm ix}}}{x^2+1} \, dx = \pm \frac\pi2 - \frac1{\sqrt\pi} \int_0^\infty \frac{i e^{\mp ix}}{\sqrt{\pm ix}} \arctan x \, dx \\
\implies I_1 - I_2 &= \pi - \sqrt{\frac2\pi} \int_0^\infty \frac{(\cos x+\sin x) \arctan x}{\sqrt x} \, dx \\
&= \pi - 2\sqrt{\frac2\pi} \int_0^\infty \left(\cos x^2 + \sin x^2\right) \arctan x^2 \, dx \\
&= \pi \erf{1}
\end{align*}$$
See here for details.

Thank you for your answer. But the Integral like $I_3$ is what I intend for; I have found this kind of problem in several textbooks about complex integration, but I failed.
